# PHP update query value always string 'NULL' instead of NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay, I have no idea what's going on here.
I have an update query that two of the three fields are working exactly as I need, but no matter how much I pre-format the value for it, it still always comes up as a quoted 'NULL' in my dumped query rather than NULL as demonstrated below.

This is how I am pre-formatting my field values;

```
$val1 = (is_null($item1Val)) ? 'NULL' : "'" . stripslashes(json_encode($item1Val)) . "'";     
$val2 = (is_null($item2Val)) ? 'NULL' : "'" . stripslashes(json_encode($item2Val)) . "'";
$val3 = (is_null($item3Val)) ? 'NULL' : "'" . trim($item3Val) . "'";
```

This is the update query string I'm using in my code. I've tried using string concatenation also and that seems to yield the exact same issue;

```
$dml = "UPDATE table SET
field_1 = $val1,
field_2 = $val2,
field_3 = $val3,
WHERE id = $id;";
```

THIS, however, is how it appears when I dump the query;

```
UPDATE table SET
field_1 = NULL,
field_2 = NULL,
field_3 = 'NULL',
WHERE id = $id;
```

I have dumped the values that are coming in as the raw data and each of them come in as true NULL values, which is precisely what I am wanting. So, if they are all coming in as true NULL values, then how is the last variable being turned into a quote value rather than the first two working exactly as desired? I have no clue what I could be missing here.

This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Did you try prepared statements,as you should do this with every mysql communication.

Comment: @nbk - No. Didn't actually consider that since the vast majority of the application uses this particular method. I'll see about converting this implementation over to a prepared statement to see how it handles the bindings. Can you dump a prepared statement prior to execution?

Comment: the prepared statemnet is always a variabke, which you can close before excuting  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( and $stmt->close();

Comment: @nbk - Not exactly sure I understand what you mean by "you can close before executing". Could you elaborate on that a little more, perhaps? Also, maybe you misunderstood my question. I was wondering if there was a way to see the resulting query it will run before it is executed? Thanks!

Comment: see the php manual https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php every prepared stament get the variabble $stmt and at the end come a close. nobody says you have to execute anything between. ot you can assign it to a new query

Comment: I did get it working via the prepared statement method. So, I'm assuming the prepared statement's binding operation must make sense out of string NULLs vs actual NULLs. If you provide your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer for my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use prepared statements, like you always should

```
dml = "UPDATE table SET field_1 = ?,field_2 = ?,field_3 = ?,WHERE id = ?;";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(dml );
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$val1, $val2,$val3, $id);
$stmt->execute();
//fetching affected rows
$stmt->close();
```

$stmt is the variable, that can be assigned new if you don't want to execute it or closed.

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive answer, nbk!

Answer (score 0):

You are using php so you should prepare the query and bind the fields :
For example :

```
$sta = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO tableName SET field_1=:field1, field_2=:field2 WHERE id=:id);

$sta->execute([
  ':field1' => $field_1,
  ':field2' => $field_2,
  ':id' => $id
]);
```

Of course the syntax depends or what framework you are using

Comment: Thanks for that reply. I'm using mysqli rather than PDO.